# Passando dados entre Activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Bom, estou fazendo um app e tenho uma tela de login que faz a conexão com o banco de dados a partir de um web service, só q estou com um problema quero pega o id do usuario e o user name para passar estes dados para outra Activity e não estou conseguindo .. Pois quando a pessoa for publicar algo preciso que salve no banco de dados o id e o nome da pessoa, alguma sugestão de como fazer isso ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Na sua **Activity 1**, use um código mais ou menos assim:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id_pessoa", "1234");
i.putExtra("nome_pessoa", "John Doe");

startActivity(i);
```

Pra recuperar os dados na sua **Activity 2**:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
    Integer idPessoa = extras.getInt("id_pessoa");
    String nomePessoa = extras.getString("nome_pessoa");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Se você for usar uma vez só o Bundle / Intent servirá, agora se quiser mante-los e recuperar depois em qualquer activity use SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MYPREF", 0); 

Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

Para inserir os dados use

```
editor.putInt("key_name", "value");
editor.putString("key_name", "value");
```

e por ai vai.

Para recuperar os dados você faz o seguinte

```
String string = pref.getString("key_name", null);

int x = pref.getInt("key_name", null);
```

Para ficar mais bonito ainda você pode criar a classe de preferencias suas

```
public class Preferences {

public static final String PREF_NAME = "your preferences name";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static final int MODE = Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE;

public static final String USER_ID = "USER_ID_NEW";
public static final String USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";

public static final String NAME = "NAME";
public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL";
public static final String PHONE = "PHONE";
public static final String address = "address";

public static void writeBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
getEditor(context).putBoolean(key, value).commit();
}

public static boolean readBoolean(Context context, String key,
    boolean defValue) {
return getPreferences(context).getBoolean(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeInteger(Context context, String key, int value) {
getEditor(context).putInt(key, value).commit();

}

public static int readInteger(Context context, String key, int defValue) {
return getPreferences(context).getInt(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeString(Context context, String key, String value)   {
getEditor(context).putString(key, value).commit();

}

public static String readString(Context context, String key, String defValue) {
return getPreferences(context).getString(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeFloat(Context context, String key, float value) {
getEditor(context).putFloat(key, value).commit();
}

public static float readFloat(Context context, String key, float defValue) {
return getPreferences(context).getFloat(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeLong(Context context, String key, long value) {
getEditor(context).putLong(key, value).commit();
}

public static long readLong(Context context, String key, long defValue) {
return getPreferences(context).getLong(key, defValue);
}

public static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE);
}

public static Editor getEditor(Context context) {
return getPreferences(context).edit();
}

}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
Preferences.writeString(getApplicationContext(),
                Preferences.NAME, "dev");

Preferences.readString(getApplicationContext(), Preferences.NAME,
                "");
```

É tudo estático mesmo ai só usar, espero  ter ajudado.