# Pegar dados de um plain text e colocar em outro em outra activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

eu tenho um app de catálogo que o cliente exigiu que fosse implementado uma função de escolha de quantidade em cada item.

Por exemplo: tenho o produto A (na ActivityA), o cliente quer 25 unidades. no produto B 05 (na ActivityB) e no produto C 47 (na ActivityC).

Eu quero pegar todos esses dados e colocar em um PlainText que fica em um formulário de contato, discriminando a quantidade e o nome de cada item. Esse formulário fica em outra Activity, chamada ActivityContato.

Como posso fazer isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Passando dados entre Activity Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128415/passando-dados-entre-activity-android)

Comment: Obrigado por apontar a possível duplicata, mas não é isso que eu quero. eu só quero pegar o dado digitado no plain text (que vai ser um numero de 0 a 999) e jogar dentro desse outro plain text que vai estar na activity do formulário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu acho que se tu fizeres isto vai resultar e vai fazer o que tu queres. (Não tenho acerteza mas experimenta)

Activity(Principal)

No (*XML*) da primeira *activity* colocas uns `editText` (e cada uma com um *id* diferente) e um Botão (Este é o botão que vais utilizar para alem de abrir a outra *activity* vais enviar os valores) e na parte do código colocas assim

```
private EditText produto_um, ...    ;//(Colocas todos os *EditText* que precisares)
private Button btn_AlgumaCoisa;
produto_um=findViewById(R.id.produto_um);
btn_AlgumaCoisa=findViewByid(R.id.btn_algumacoisa);
btn_AlgumaCoisa.setOnclic...(new View...)
{
//Aqui pegas todos os valores que estam nos *EditText*
String valorUm=produto_um.getText.toString();  
//(Fazes isto para cada *EditText* pois tens de pegar todos eles um a um)
//Depois de pegares todos os valores dos *EditText*
//É só tu fazeres uma *Intent* para abrir a outra *Activity*

Intent abrirePassardados=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityContato.class);
abrirePassardados.putExtra("valor",valorUm); 
starActivity(abrirePassardados);   //(Atencao coloca o metodo que diz Intent 
intent senão ele não ira funcionar)
}

Activity (Contato)
```

no codigo

```
Bundle dados=getInten().getExtra();

String alguma_coisa=dados.getString(valor);

//por fim colocas esta String alguma_coisa

Componente.setText(""+alguma_coisa);
```

//Mais ou menos é isto mas tens de criar um xml com TextView ou qualquer outra componente e pronto espero ter ajudado.
Bom fim de semana.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!